# fadeOut() parent element comes back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a search function that has to hide the divs that don't match the search criteria.

**HTML from elements**

```
<div class="form-group" id="number">
  <input class="form-control tfInput" id="tfInput1" type="text" value="test">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="update1"> Save
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Delete" id="delete1">Delete
  </button>
</div>
```

There are multiple of these divs that get loaded into the page.
All these divs have the class `.tfInput` and get appended to the form with id `"list"`.

**HTML where the divs get loaded into**

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="searchElement" style="width: 200px" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="search()">search</button>
    </div>
</form>



<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" id="list"></form>
</div>
```

There is a search box with id `"searchElement"` and the search function gets called when a button is clicked or with a `keyup()` event in the search box.

**Javascript**

```
function search() {
  $.each($('#list .tfInput'), function(index, input) {
    if (new RegExp($('#searchElement').val().toUpperCase()).test(input.value.toUpperCase())) {
      $(input).parent().show();
    } else {
      $(input).parent().fadeOut();
    }
  })
};
```

**Problem**

The divs fadeout BUT they reappear within the same second.
They never stay hidden.
Anyone a solution?

Thx

Comment: When do you call `search()` ?

Comment: While formatting, use code sample, not snippet if you only want to show a fragment of code, not working example.

Comment: Please provide you complete html with search box also

Comment: @Rayon the function is called when the search button is clicked or when a keyup-event takes place in the input field.

Comment: Have you tried using hide()? Insert console.log in each of the branches of the IF statement and see if and when they are triggered.

Comment: @ManuelCheța Yes, hide() doesn't work either because the divs hide but reappear immediately so you don't see anything happen. I used console.log and everything gets called at the right time.

Comment: I have never used input for the same reason. Instead, i usually use the 'index' param, so i get the element with that index and do operations for that. Try it, it should work

Comment: What you posted seems to [work as intended](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/h8y47u28/). Check your console for any errors or provide a [mcve] reproducing the problem you are describing. Without one, you can't get anything but second guesses.

Comment: Have you verified that the elements showing up again is not simply due to a page reload, triggered by (accidental) actual submission of the form …?

Comment: I fixed it! Stupid mistake from myself. Still learning :) I added an answer myself, don't know if that's the proper method?

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed now.

I changed some css property because bootstrap didn't do what I expected.

That was the error that messed everything up.

My error? I changed the `display` property for all the divs to `block !important` and because of that they kept reappearing.

Thanks for all the input!

Comment: didn't see that comming :) There are sevral reasons why using !important is not advaisable :)

Comment: will avoid using !important in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem :) Try to block your button, like:

```
 $("#Button").click(
             function(event) {
                  $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                  event.preventDefault();
                  //your code
                  $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            };
);
```

For unknown reason javascript likes to interprete clicking as double-clicking.
**Also if your elements has a default "mode" it can go back to it. To prevent it we just used event.preventDefault()**
Third option is that you are hiding it somewhere else.
Forth option: you are using each tfInput element. So it finds first -hide inputs parent. Finds second - show inputs parent. Finds third - hide inputs parent again ect. **It toggles the same element.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$( input ).fadeOut( "slow" );
```